# React to blur event in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an input textbox and whenever it loses focus I want to get its value text in a function.

For example, if type `"testimonials1"`, how could I get that text in an event handler for the `blur` event?

This is what I tried. I get `ProjectTestimonial` as an object, not user-typed text.

HMTL

```html
<div class="ratingcontents" data-bind="foreach: ProjectTestimonial">
  <!--ko if: !Testimonialstext-->
  <input type="text" placeholder="Testimonials" class="txttestimonials" 
    data-bind="
      text: Testimonialstext,
      event: { 
        blur: $root.testimonialblurFunction.bind(SourceId, SourceText, Testimonialstext)
      }
    " 
  >
  <!--/ko-->
</div>
```

JS

```
self.testimonialblurFunction = function (data, event, Testimonialstext) {
    debugger;
    alert(data.soid + Testimonialstext);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the input's value would be part of the event handler parameters?

Comment: i really dont know!, can you correct it?

Comment: Also, please explain *why* you want the text in the `blur` handler. It seems to me that you are not using knockout right. And you need to show your view model (`ProjectTestimonial` and everything in it).

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/gb9e9/ - is this what you need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first mistake you made was using the 'text' binding on the input field, rather than the 'value' binding.

Regarding the event handler, I would not do this. I would use knockout's 'subscribe' functionality to listen for changes to the observable.

Here is a [Jsfiddle version of your code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9pYk/) I have changed your markup to demonstrate more clearly.

HTML

```
<div class="ratingcontents" data-bind="foreach: ProjectTestimonial">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Testimonials" class="txttestimonials"  
    data-bind="value: Testimonialstext" />

</div>
```

Javascript

```
function viewModel(jsModel){
    var self = this;

    self.ProjectTestimonial = ko.utils.arrayMap(jsModel, function(item) {
        return new testimonial(item);
    }); 
}

function testimonial(jsTestimonial){
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(jsTestimonial, {}, self);

    self.Testimonialstext.subscribe(function(){
        alert(self.SourceId() + self.Testimonialstext());        
    });
}

var rawModel = [
    {
        SourceId: '1',
        SourceText: 'Foo',
        Testimonialstext: 'Ahoy there.'
    },
    {
        SourceId: '2',
        SourceText: 'Bar',
        Testimonialstext: 'Blah blah blah'
}];

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(rawModel));
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use event, that attaches to any JS event:

```
<input name="id" data-bind="value: id, event: { blur: blurFunction }">
```

And in your view model:

```
self.blurFuncion = function(){
    // this attacks when blur event occurs in input
}
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [has focus](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) binding instead. From what I understand you want the data in the text box once the user stops editing. This is simple enough. Check  out this example from the knockout js documentation page.

```
<p>
Hello  <b data-bind="text:name"></b> </p>   
<input data-bind="value: name, hasfocus: editing" />

<p><em>Click the name to edit it; click elsewhere to apply changes.</em></p>
```

View model

```
function PersonViewModel(name) {
// Data
this.name = ko.observable(name);
this.editing = ko.observable(false);

// Behaviors
this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel("Bert Bertington"));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQnVu/3/)

Comment: Blur works fine for losing focus :) The example above is for toggling.